# GC Alloc become high with one of API call and app become hang and then crash Okhttp and Retrofit [Android]

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, retrofit2, okhttp

In application.
During app start, It starts one Handler Service, and from it, the system call the Retrofit API request.

Below is code for the Retrofit Client object creation SingleTon Object.

```
            val httpLogger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            httpLogger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(httpLogger)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)

            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(APP_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient.build())
                    .build()
```

Below is API Call Place holder code reference.

```
Call<User> call = apiService.createuser(user);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

  }
```

But don't know why the app is become hung due to some king of Heap increase after above API call.

Crash call with Debug APK.

```
2022-03-30 20:55:09.760 16017-16111/com.app.app I/zygote64: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 255MB/256MB, paused 34us total 535.453ms
2022-03-30 20:55:09.760 16017-16111/com.app.app I/zygote64: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 32B allocation
2022-03-30 20:55:09.760 16017-16111/com.app.app I/zygote64: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:09.760 16017-16035/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
2022-03-30 20:55:09.760 16017-16026/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:09.760 16017-16017/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:09.760 16017-16029/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.254 16017-16315/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.662 16017-16111/com.app.app I/zygote64: Clamp target GC heap from 279MB to 256MB
2022-03-30 20:55:10.662 16017-16111/com.app.app I/zygote64: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 255MB/256MB, paused 33us total 902.399ms
2022-03-30 20:55:10.662 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 32 byte allocation with 8 free bytes and 8B until OOM, max allowed footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456" (recursive case)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16035/com.app.app I/zygote64: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 8.429s
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64: "OkHttp https://login.microsoftonline.com/..." prio=5 tid=35 Runnable
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12c528c8 self=0x741bbf6600
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:   | sysTid=16111 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x74109ff4f0
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:   | state=R schedstat=( 26183090935 411768191 4477 ) utm=2290 stm=328 core=4 HZ=100
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:   | stack=0x74108fd000-0x74108ff000 stackSize=1037KB
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.util.DerValue.encode(DerValue.java:418)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.util.DerValue.toByteArray(DerValue.java:861)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.x509.X509CRLEntryImpl.parse(X509CRLEntryImpl.java:456)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.x509.X509CRLEntryImpl.<init>(X509CRLEntryImpl.java:133)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.x509.X509CRLImpl.parse(X509CRLImpl.java:1161)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.x509.X509CRLImpl.<init>(X509CRLImpl.java:146)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.intern(X509Factory.java:206)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.x509.X509CRLImpl.toImpl(X509CRLImpl.java:1235)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.DistributionPointFetcher.verifyCRL(DistributionPointFetcher.java:331)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.DistributionPointFetcher.getCRLs(DistributionPointFetcher.java:209)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.DistributionPointFetcher.getCRLs(DistributionPointFetcher.java:121)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs(RevocationChecker.java:552)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs(RevocationChecker.java:465)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:394)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:337)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:301)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:703)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.663 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:197)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:399)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native method)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.doHandshake(SslWrapper.java:374)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:217)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:154)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app W/zygote64:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2022-03-30 20:55:10.664 16017-16111/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.665 16017-16017/com.app.app I/zygote64: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ProfileSaver for 8.160s
2022-03-30 20:55:10.665 16017-16017/com.app.app I/zygote64: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.665 16017-16017/com.app.app I/zygote64: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.665 16017-16026/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.665 16017-16029/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.665 16017-16111/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.665 16017-16315/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-03-30 20:55:10.738 16017-16023/com.app.app I/zygote64: Thread[3,tid=16023,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x744b024200,peer=0x12c4cf90,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2022-03-30 20:55:10.742 16017-16023/com.app.app I/zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
2022-03-30 20:55:10.885 16017-16017/com.app.app I/zygote64: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 3307327(81MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(168MB) LOS objects, 49% free, 6MB/13MB, paused 64us total 220.571ms
2022-03-30 20:55:10.896 16017-16028/com.app.app I/zygote64: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Background on ProfileSaver for 7.860s
2022-03-30 20:55:10.897 16017-16026/com.app.app I/zygote64: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ProfileSaver for 6.785s
```

Crash log with Release apk.

```
2022-03-30 21:29:15.964 16911-17001/com.app.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.app.app, PID: 16911
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 48 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM, max allowed footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456
        at sun.security.util.DerInputBuffer.getBigInteger(DerInputBuffer.java:170)
        at sun.security.util.DerValue.getBigInteger(DerValue.java:529)
        at sun.security.x509.SerialNumber.construct(SerialNumber.java:44)
        at sun.security.x509.SerialNumber.<init>(SerialNumber.java:86)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CRLEntryImpl.parse(X509CRLEntryImpl.java:460)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CRLEntryImpl.<init>(X509CRLEntryImpl.java:133)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CRLImpl.parse(X509CRLImpl.java:1161)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CRLImpl.<init>(X509CRLImpl.java:146)
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.intern(X509Factory.java:206)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CRLImpl.toImpl(X509CRLImpl.java:1235)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.DistributionPointFetcher.verifyCRL(DistributionPointFetcher.java:331)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.DistributionPointFetcher.getCRLs(DistributionPointFetcher.java:209)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.DistributionPointFetcher.getCRLs(DistributionPointFetcher.java:121)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs(RevocationChecker.java:552)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs(RevocationChecker.java:465)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:394)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:337)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:301)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:703)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:560)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:605)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:197)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:399)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.doHandshake(SslWrapper.java:374)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:217)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(Unknown Source:72)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(Unknown Source:52)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(Unknown Source:196)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(Unknown Source:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(Unknown Source:0)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(Unknown Source:47)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(Unknown Source:31)
2022-03-30 21:29:15.964 16911-17001/com.app.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:11)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:166)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:191)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:166)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:167)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:166)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:34)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:166)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(Unknown Source:492)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Unknown Source:166)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(Unknown Source:113)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(Unknown Source:51)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**NOTE: I am observing this only when my device system time is set to Future time like 5-10 days ahead. My Device is a Custom android device having software 8.1**

Comment: I found similar issue here https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/520

Comment: If you are faking the date, all your SSL connections will likely fail.  Certificates can have a tight validity range. Maybe it's retrying repeatedly.  An en event listener to see what activity is happening.

Comment: But that bug looks like the root cause.  Nice find.

Comment: Will adding this make any difference https://blog.codavel.com/accepting-self-signed-certificates-in-okhttp3

Comment: Good idea, let's continue on the bug.